# Querying array of nested objects with nested array of objects in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum, partiql

Let's say I have the following JSON

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "sets": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "value": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "value": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If the table name is `X` I expect the query

```sql
 SELECT x.id, v.value 
 FROM X as x,
   x.sets as sets,
   sets.values as v
```

to give me

```
id, value
1, 1
1, 2
2, 5
2, 6
```

and it does work if both sets and values has **one** object each. When there's more the query fails with column 'id' had 0 remaining values but expected 2. Seems to me I'm not iterating over "sets" properly?

So my question is: what's the proper way to query data structured like my example above in Redshift (using PartiQL)?